# Formatting numbers in a td

Tags: javascript, html, pug

My code gets some totals that look like this:

```
var totals = { someInt:5, someFloat:7.555, someNumberIDoNotNeed:7};
```

I'd like to present a subset of these in a table in a view (via a jade template).  My idea was to put the ones I want into an object, then let JSON.stringify do the formatting for me.  I wanted one of the values to be rendered boldface:

```
var needed = {};
needed["The int is"] = parseFloat(totals.someInt);
needed["The float is"] = "<b>" + parseFloat(totals.someFloat).toFixed(2).toString() + "</b>";

// get rid of the curly braces and add a space after the commas
var string = JSON.stringify(needed).replace(/[{}"]/gi, '').replace(/,/gi, ', ');
```

Then in my jade view:

```
td= string
```

Reviewing this in the Chrome inspector, the string seems to be what I hoped for:

```
<td>
    "The int is:5, The float is:<b>7.55</b>"
</td>
```

But the browser isn't respecting the  markup.  I just see the braces and b (< b >) in the output.  I've tried a few variants in formatting the output, but the basic problem of the marking showing remains the same.  Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

(I tried to quote the output using SO's > quote formatting, but it actually respects the  in my markup, and this question shows up with the bold output just how I want it.  Somehow SO gets this right but I cannot!)

Comment: Since [`toFixed()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5) returns a String, `.toFixed().toString()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Jade before, but I took a quick look at their editable demos and reference and noticed that `td= string` syntax escapes html entities but `td != string` does not.

So that seems to be your problem. You want to keep the html intact in this case. So give `td != string` a try.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks so much!  I tried all kinds of javascript tricks, the jade problem never occurred to me!